# Point inside a rectangle - On which side of the diagonal is it?

Tags: coordinates, rectangles, diagonal

So, I have a rectangle divided into two triangles and I have a point:

[image: Rectangle]

I know the coordinates of the four vertices of the rectangle (A, B, C and D) and I know the coordinates of P. What I need to know is in which of the two triangles is the point.

I think it's a really simple thing to do, but apparently I can't figure it out by myself.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are couple of ways to tackle this. But the easiest and most straight forward is to check for the slope.

For your example, if slope `AP` is lesser than slope `AD` then point `P` is above the `AD` line and vice versa. If the slope is the same, then it is on the same line.

**Edit:**

Assume the following

```
A -> (0,3)
B -> (3,3)
C -> (0,0)
D -> (3,0)
```

Then the slope `AD` is `(3-0)/(3-0) = 1`. Assume that `P` is at `(2,2)`, then slope `AP` is `(2-3)/(2-0) = -1/2`.

We have `AD` > `AP`, thus point `P` must be above the line `AD`. Notice that point `P` needs to cross `AD` in order to be below the line, and thus the slope changes.

Comment: Much easier solution than mine :)

Comment: To avoid divide-by-zero, cross multiply the inequality. Instead of testing (y1-y2)/(x1-x2) < (y1-yp)/(x1-xp), test  (y1-y2)*(x1-xp) < (y1-yp)*(x1-x2).

Answer (score 2):

You could consider vector **AP** and vector **AD**. Compute the cross product of these two vectors. The sign of the cross product will tell you what side of the diagonal the point is on.

More information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product